# SimpleRepository classes and namespace missing

Tags: subsonic

I am using SubSonic Active Record in a C# web application. I followed all the setup instructions and went well. i queried the database for some simple results and presto I got data. I then changed the namespace in the settings file right clicked on the ActiveRecord file and everything broke. Since then any classes and namespace generated in the ActiveRecord.cs file is not included in the project. Its like the file and the code inside ActiveRecord.cs do not exist or visual studio cannot process or recognize the files. I inspected the file and all seems well.

I am using TFS2008 if that may be the cause. I did notice earlier I also had an issue with System.Data if I pressed System. no Data namespace? This subsequently fixed itself somehow? and now I'm left trying to access the SubSonic generated classes and namespace.

Any ideas?

tks Hans

Comment: Do you have references to the subsonic assembly? What language?

Comment: I have a reference to the SubSonic.Core assembly. I have created a new web app hoping to solve the issue but no luck. Subsonic generates the relevant classes etc. The class file is there and looks great. The project compiles but I cannot access the namespace in the class file? Its really strange. I even tried the restart yr machine trick.

Comment: OK guys it seems this is a VS2008 TFS issue. I manually added the App_Code folder to my web as it was not on the list of ASP.NET folders. That was the first funny. Any classes I created in the App_Code folder are completely ignored by VS. Its like VS does not see the App_Code folder at all. I can even craete deliberate typos in a class like using System.XXX; no compiler error! does anyone know whats going on here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure your project file is checked out - probably solution file too. TFS locks these things and you can't add files in unless the mechanism (your proj file) is unlocked.